# Why does the NumberFormat returns blank fields?

Tags: java

So a few days ago I encountered a weird problem however, I didn't change any that kind of code. The problem is the format I'm getting from my method which I used for years. All commas are now spaces (blank fields) and I have no idea what is causing this.

```java
public static String toFancyCost(int num) {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance().format((Integer) num);
}
```

Before even this happened the `String` I received was looking like for example `2,181,273` and not like `2 181 273`.

Comment: Did you change your system locale?

Comment: I don't think so, I did not

Comment: Please try with locale. - NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format((Integer) num);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have changed your system locale by accident. The implementation of NumberFormat.getInstance() *(on 1.8.0_131)*:

```
public final static NumberFormat getInstance() {
    return getInstance(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT), NUMBERSTYLE);
}
```

It uses formatting specified by the default locale. [and the java docs on Locale.getDefault say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()):

> The Java Virtual Machine sets the default locale during startup **based**
>   **on the host environment**. It is used by many locale-sensitive methods
>   if no locale is explicitly specified. It can be changed using the
>   setDefault method.

If you were to use [NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)) you can specify which locale the `NumberFormat` should use.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!
I changed the locale to Locale.US and it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your systems default local is using a space as thousands separator,  number format retured by `getInstance()` uses settings from system's default local.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, somehow the system default may have been modified. Let's stick the code to set the locale when formatting by using below to avoid any issues.

```
int number = 345678987;

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);// Locale.US or any other locale you required
String numberAsString = numberFormat.format(number);
System.out.println(numberAsString);
```

response:

```
345,678,987
```

when I use the below for example with Locale.CANADA_FRENCH

```
 int number = 345678987;
 NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
 String numberAsString = numberFormat.format(number);
 System.out.println(numberAsString);
```

response:

```
345 678 987
```

So in your case also locale may have been causing issues, so please explictly set locale.